# Routing application traffic through specific WIRELESS network interface

Tags: networking, wireless, routing

I've seen quite a few tutorials, more or less complete, about forcing an application to use a certain/specific network interface, however, all such tutorials deal with **wired** interfaces. The most promising method I've seen is via network namespaces (**netns**): I know, however, that `ip link set` does **not** work with wireless ifaces, so one has to use `iw phy ... set netns name ...,` and, using that, I tried adapting the [tutorials](https://quantum5.ca/2020/01/03/run-linux-program-different-network-interface/) to wireless ifaces, to no avail.

Could we please have someone post a sequence of commands to achieve that?

Feel free to assume that the wireless interface is named "phy0," and the new network namespace is "savanna." Also know that DHCP assigns phy0 a static address.